# compiler not finding headers when cross compiling

Tags: cmake, cross-compiling

I created a cross compiler for the jetson nano using the following bash script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e

# mkdir cross-scratchpad
# cd cross-scratchpad
# FILES="http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/binutils/binutils-2.36.tar.gz
# http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/gcc/gcc-11.1.0/gcc-11.1.0.tar.gz &
# http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/glibc/glibc-2.33.tar.xz &
# http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/mpfr/mpfr-4.1.0.tar.xz
# http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/gmp/gmp-6.2.1.tar.xz & 
# http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/mpc/mpc-1.2.1.tar.gz &
# ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/isl-0.18.0.tar.bz2
# ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/cloog-0.18.1.tar.gz
# https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/l4t/r32_release_v5.2/sources/t210/public_sources.tbz2"
# echo "$FILES" | xargs -n 1 -P 5 wget
# wait
for f in *.tar*; do tar xf "$f"; done
cd gcc-11.1.0
ln -s ../mpfr-4.1.0 mpfr
ln -s ../gmp-6.2.1 gmp
ln -s ../mpc-1.2.1 mpc
ln -s ../isl-0.18 isl
ln -s ../cloog-0.18.1 cloog
cd ..
sudo rm -rf /opt/cross/*
export PATH=/opt/cross/bin:"$PATH"
mkdir build-binutils
cd build-binutils
../binutils-2.36/configure --prefix=/opt/cross --target=aarch64-linux --disable-multilib --disable-werror
make -j8
make install
cd ..
tar -xjf public_sources.tbz2
cd Linux_for_Tegra/source/public/
tar -xjf kernel_src.tbz2
cd kernel/kernel-4.9
make ARCH=arm64 INSTALL_HDR_PATH=/opt/cross/aarch64-linux headers_install
cd ../../../../..
mkdir -p build-gcc
cd build-gcc
../gcc-11.1.0/configure --prefix=/opt/cross --target=aarch64-linux --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-multilib --disable-werror
make -j8 all-gcc
make install-gcc
cd ..
mkdir -p build-glibc
cd build-glibc
../glibc-2.33/configure --prefix=/opt/cross/aarch64-linux --build="$MACHTYPE" --host=aarch64-linux --target=aarch64-linux --with-headers=/opt/cross/aarch64-linux/include --disable-multilib --disable-werror libc_cv_forced_unwind=yes
make install-bootstrap-headers=yes install-headers
make -j8 csu/subdir_lib
install csu/crt1.o csu/crti.o csu/crtn.o /opt/cross/aarch64-linux/lib
aarch64-linux-gcc -nostdlib -nostartfiles -shared -x c /dev/null -o /opt/cross/aarch64-linux/lib/libc.so
touch /opt/cross/aarch64-linux/include/gnu/stubs.h
cd ..
cd build-gcc
make -j8 all-target-libgcc
make install-target-libgcc
cd ..
cd build-glibc
make -j8
make install
cd ..
cd build-gcc
make -j8
make install
cd ..
```

I am now trying to use it with cmake to build a project.

I have written the following toolchain file to use when creating the makefile with CMake:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH path/to/root/of/jetson/nano)

set(CROSS_ROOT /opt/cross/bin)

set(CMAKE_AR                        ${CROSS_ROOT}/aarch64-linux-ar)
set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER              ${CROSS_ROOT}/aarch64-linux-as)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER                ${CROSS_ROOT}/aarch64-linux-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER              ${CROSS_ROOT}/aarch64-linux-g++)
set(CMAKE_LINKER                    ${CROSS_ROOT}/aarch64-linux-ld)
set(CMAKE_OBJCOPY                   ${CROSS_ROOT}/aarch64-linux-objcopy)
set(CMAKE_RANLIB                    ${CROSS_ROOT}/aarch64-linux-ranlib)
set(CMAKE_SIZE                      ${CROSS_ROOT}/aarch64-linux-size)
set(CMAKE_STRIP                     ${CROSS_ROOT}/aarch64-linux-strip)
set(CMAKE_GCOV                      ${CROSS_ROOT}/aarch64-linux-gcov)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS                   "${APP_C_FLAGS} -Wno-psabi" CACHE INTERNAL "")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS                 "${APP_CXX_FLAGS} ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}" CACHE INTERNAL "")

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG             "-O0 -g" CACHE INTERNAL "")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE           "-O3 -DNDEBUG" CACHE INTERNAL "")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG           "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG}" CACHE INTERNAL "")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE         "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE}" CACHE INTERNAL "")

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

The `path/to/root/of/jetson/nano` is a path to a root directory I created using rsync. The project compiles fine when I run `cmake .. && make -j8` on the target machine.

Configuring on the host machine using `cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../toolchain.cmake`  succeeds with:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.1.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.1.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /opt/cross/bin/aarch64-linux-gcc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /opt/cross/bin/aarch64-linux-g++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found OpenCV: /usr (found version "4.5.3") 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /path/to/my/project/build
```

However, when I run `make -j8` I get an error on every include in the form:

```
fatal error: glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp: No such file or directory
    4 | #include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
```

What's going on and how do I fix this?

Comment: "**CMake** does not find any of my headers" - how do you search for headers in cmake? Do you call `try_compile`? Are you sure it's cmake, not compiler, who does not find the headers? Please post the error message and please post the verbose output from build system (if you build, does cmake stop at configuration stage?) please post the compilation command?

Comment: Shouldn't your toolchain set a **sysroot** for your compiler? The sysroot is set via `CMAKE_SYSROOT` variable.

Comment: @Tsyvarev different sources say different things, I've tried both but it seems to make no difference

Comment: @KamilCuk I've made the relevant edits

Comment: Oh, it cannot find some 3d-party header (`glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp`). It is unlikely that a toolchain is involved into the problem. Probably, the CMake project you build has some problems with cross-compiling. Note, that no line in your toolchain adds an include directory.  Variable `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` just hints CMake for searching a directory with a header. The search itself (with `find_path`) and using the directory found is up to the CMake project.

Comment: @Tsyvarev is the solution here hardcoding the directories in the filesystem of the target into include calls in the toolchain file or is there something more elegant I can do? My CMake project only finds CMake using find_package but it seems that that call finds opencv on the host and not the target system.

Comment: Use additionally `set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)` and CMake won't search packages on the host. But it seems that your target lacks for OpenCV installation (otherwise CMake would prefer target installation to the host one).

Comment: @Tsyvarev I have made the changes and CMake no longer finds OpenCV. However, When run find ../path/to/embedded/fs/root -name OpenCVConfig.cmake I do find the required file in ../path/to/embedded/fs/root/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/cmake/opencv4/OpenCVConfig.cmake

Comment: @Tsyvarev in fact all the libraries I want can be found in ../path/to/embedded/fs/root/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/